# How to pass variadic function parameters to another function in C++ (specifically std::format)?

Tags: c++, c++20, variadic

I'm trying to write a logger that can take arguments the same way that `printf` does with formatting supported. I'm planning to just call `std::format` on the input to my logger, but I need to forward the variadic args to `std::format`. How can I do that?

What I want it too look like:

```
void log(const std::string& msg)
{
  std::cout << msg << std::endl; // I'm actually wrapping another logger here, this is just an example.
}

void log(const std::string& fmt_string ...);
{
  std::string msg = std::format(gmt_string, ...);
  log(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want the C-style `...` parameter. You want a variadic template:

```
template <typename T, typename ...P>
void log(T &&format, P &&... params)
{
    std::string msg = fmt::format(std::forward<T>(format), std::forward<P>(params)...);
    std::cout << msg << '\n';
}
```

Notice forwarding references for the parameter, pack instead of const references. Const references had caused problems for me before (spdlog used to use const references, and `fmt::join` didn't like them).

Notice the first parameter being templated. At least with libfmt, this is necessary to be able to receive `FMT_STRING(...)` parameters. With `std::format`, an `std::string_view` would probably suffice. `const std::string &` is uncool because it forces a heap allocation.

Also I'm not sure how I feel about having a separate parameter-less overload. It means that you have to escape `{` and `}` *only* when there's at least one parameter, which is not nice.

Also consider using [spdlog](https://github.com/gabime/spdlog), which is very similar. It wraps libfmt, and can direct output to various/arbirary targets.

Comment: Worth noting this is called a [parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) for better searchability.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a [template parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) and [`std::forward`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward), e.g.:

```
template <class... Args>
void log(const std::string& fmt_string, Args&&... args)
{
  std::string msg = std::format(fmt_string, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  log(msg);
}
```